# Does the intensity of LED lights decrease after turning on?

Tags: time, light-emitting-diodes, intensity

LED lights come on immediately the power is supplied. This is different to the older compact fluorescent-tube lights. I am always impressed by the brightness of the LED lights when they come on. Later on, though, they do not seem to be quite so bright.

Is this a real effect or am I just getting adjusted to the light intensity?

related (?) [Why does the intensity of a LED change as the temperature increases](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290140/why-does-the-intensity-of-a-led-change-as-the-temperature-increases)